# slurm: frontend as compute node not responding

Tags: slurm

Similar to [slurm: use a control node also for computing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23497004/slurm-use-a-control-node-also-for-computing).

I would like to use the frontend as an compute node. I made the following entries in `slurm.conf`

```
NodeName=gisc RealMemory=63000 Sockets=1 CoresPerSocket=8 ThreadsPerCore=2 State=UNKNOWN Weight=2
NodeName=c[0-2] RealMemory=126000 Sockets=1 CoresPerSocket=16 ThreadsPerCore=2 State=UNKNOWN Weight=1
PartitionName=normal Nodes=gisc,c[0-2] Default=YES MaxTime=INFINITE State=UP
```

And restarted both `slurmd` and `slurmctld`.
However, I always get no response from the frontend node which is proved by an asterix in the status.

```
PARTITION AVAIL  TIMELIMIT  NODES  STATE NODELIST
normal*      up   infinite      1  idle* gisc
normal*      up   infinite      2  alloc c[0-1]
normal*      up   infinite      1   idle c2
```

Also, I cannot start `slurmd` on the frontend node. The logs do not help.
Could it be that `slurmd` and `slurmctld` are conflicting on the frontend node?

My `/etc/hosts` looks as follows

```
192.168.1.1 gisc.localdomain gisc gisc-eth0.localdomain gisc-eth0

### ALL ENTRIES BELOW THIS LINE WILL BE OVERWRITTEN BY WAREWULF ###
#
# See provision.conf for configuration paramaters


# Node Entry for node: c0 (ID=22)
192.168.1.2             c0.localdomain c0 c0-eth0.localdomain c0-eth0

# Node Entry for node: c1 (ID=23)
192.168.1.3             c1.localdomain c1 c1-eth0.localdomain c1-eth0

# Node Entry for node: c2 (ID=24)
192.168.1.4             c2.localdomain c2 c2-eth0.localdomain c2-eth0
```

Comment: Can you execute "slurmd -C" in the frontend and show the output?

Comment: `command not found` - probably because `slurmd` is not running / cannot be started on the frontend.

Comment: Add the installation path to your path (slurm bin and sbin directories). To execute that command, you do not need to have running the slurmd daemon.

Answer (score 1):

*facepalm* The `slurm-client` library was missing on the frontend. Only the `slurm-server` library was installed...